How to force Angular to update the signals?
I have a service:
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WeatherCardsService {
  constructor() {}

  selectedRegion = signal('Signal Region');
  selectedCity = signal('Signal City');

  mainCities: any[] = [
    {
      city: 'Puerto rico',
      temperature: 25,
      desc: 'Take sunglasses and use SPF cream.',
      url: '../../../../../assets/weather/sunny.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Wrocław',
      temperature: 13,
      desc: 'First days of spring are comming.',
      url: '../../../../../assets/weather/autumnly.jpg',
    },
    {
      city: 'Yakutsk',
      temperature: -10,
      desc: 'Wear a thick jacket and gloves.',
      url: '../../../../../assets/weather/snowy.jpg',
    },
  ];
  getCards() {
    return this.mainCities;
  }

  getCitiesArray() {
    return this.citiesArrays;
  }

  getRegionsArray() {
    return this.regionArrays;
  }

  setSelectedRegion(region: string) {
    this.selectedRegion.set(region);
    console.log(this.selectedRegion);
  }
  setSelectedCity(city: string) {
    this.selectedCity.set(city);
  }
  getSelectedRegion() {
    return this.selectedRegion();
  }
  getSelectedCity() {
    return this.selectedCity();
  }

  citiesArrays: string[] = ['Wrocław', 'New York', 'Tokyo'];
  regionArrays: string[] = [
    'Europe',
    'Asia',
    'North America',
    'South America',
    'Oceania',
    'Africa',
  ];

}

component.ts
  constructor(private weatherCardsService: WeatherCardsService) {}
  test: string = 'test';
  selectedCityFromSignal = this.weatherCardsService.getSelectedCity();
  selectedRegionFromSignal = this.weatherCardsService.getSelectedRegion();
  citiesArrays: string[] = [];
  regionArrays: string[] = [];
  getCities() {
    this.citiesArrays = this.weatherCardsService.getCitiesArray();
  }
  getRegions() {
    this.regionArrays = this.weatherCardsService.getRegionsArray();
  }

and html:
{{ selectedCityFromSignal }}
{{ selectedRegionFromSignal }}

the value chages are called in form:
  (change)="setCity(city.value)"


 setCity(city: string) {
    console.log(city);
    this.weatherCardsService.setSelectedCity(city);
  }

the problem is that the console.logs are correct but the value in the html is always inital and never got updated.
How to force Angular to update the signals and keep the values always up to date as singals in service are changed?

Your code (selectedCityFromSignal = this.weatherCardsService.getSelectedCity();
) is a one time assignment. So it is clear the value is not updated. So use the signal in the template directly or create your own (for example by using computed)

how to use signal directly in html?

Signals in templates can be used by calling them as function: myFanzySignal()

Expose the signal as a read only and use this instead of the getter. As a signal can be called a softer as wanted without side effect you need no getter. But ensure not to expose the writeable signal if you don’t want to set the value this way outside the service

i think use this
getSelectedRegion() {
    return computed(this.selectedRegion);
}

getSelectedCity() {
    return computed(this.selectedCity);
}


thanks for help, but now i get [Computed: Signal City] [Computed: Signal Region]

try this:  return computed(this.selectedRegion)()

Please don’t do this, please check out the documentation of signals. Using a computed this way in a getter ist not a good idea.
